# Self-Intersection number

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth variety of dimension $n$ and $D$ a weil divisor on X, 
How one calculate the self intersection number $D^n$? is it an element of $A^n(X)$ (chow ring of $X$)? 
Is it related with the degree of $D$?

Thanks

Comment: If $X$ were a surface and $D$ a curve on $X$, would you know how to calculate $D^2$?

Comment: no, could you explain please

Comment: OK, well instead of explaining it here, I suggest you read about it in Shafarevich, _Basic Algebraic Geometry_ Volume 1 Chapter 4. Once you digest that, you could try Chapter 1 of Lazarsfeld for higher intersection numbers, or Fulton's _Intersection Theory_ for intersections as elements of the Chow ring.